# Developing GUI for a linux executable

Tags: linux, gui, binary, development

I am looking for guide/tips on developing a graphical user interface (GUI) for a Linux executable that I am interested on. How do I go about doing it? What applications/resources do I need?

Comment: google for gui frameworks, install them, try out the code examples?

Comment: Sorry but requests for learning materials are off topic.

Comment: @rmf Do you need it to be open-source. Do you need dual-license. What target distributions, what features needed. Take a look at GTK, ncurses, X11 api, etc. Perhaps find an open-source app that has a GUI you like. Review its source code to see what they used. Research research research.

Comment: >thrig Thansk for the suggestion. @mrflash818 The exact details don't matter. It's still an early idea. Strange abbreviations like GTK, QT.. etc are what I am looking for. So i can look them up further.

>andcoz Apologies for posting an off-topic subject. Where do you reckon is a suitable place for such questions?

Comment: Wikipedia has a [list of widget toolkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits). Widget = Window + Gadget = GUI element. Most of these toolkits have bindings for lots of programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

You need the compiler, dev libraries, header files, etc. for generic programming "stuff".

Then you need to decide on a GUI tool kit to use - GTK, QT, wxWidgets, etc - or choose to reimplement the wheel and do it all yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't necessarily want to develop the GUI elements from scratch. I am hoping to use existing GUI elements to fit with my program, which is only command-line at the moment.

Comment: @rmf Right, that is why you pick an exiting toolkit to start with.  Depending on your program you could even script up a quick front end in `zenity`